# use await in nested dict comprehension

Tags: python, python-asyncio, dictionary-comprehension

I am a new to asyncio.
I have found a solution but it seems not that graceful. So I come here to ask for better advice.

I am tring to get a dict looks like that:

```
    {
        shard1:  {
                    room1:room1_objs,
                    room2:room2_objs
                },
        shard2: {...}
    }
```

here is how I tried at first.

```
async def func():
......
    # self.room_objects() simply calls GET method from aiohttp
    res = {
           shard: 
              {room: await self.room_objects(room=room, shard=shard) for room in shard_rooms_list}
              for
              shard, shard_rooms_list
              in
              user_rooms.items()
          }
```

it results in an error: SyntaxError: asynchronous comprehension outside of an asynchronous function

I guess that the nested dict comprehension do not have a async environment because of the outer dict comprehension.

so I tried to replace the outer "for" with "async for", anyway I can not find a way to implement an async iterator for build-in dict.

finally I use the code below to get rid of the nested dict comprehension.

It does work, but is there a better solution? (using dict comprehension)

```
        res = {
            shard:
                dict(zip(shard_rooms, await asyncio.gather(
                    *[self.room_objects(room=room, shard=shard) for room in shard_rooms])))
            for
            shard, shard_rooms
            in
            user_rooms.items()
        }
```

Comment: This is a [know issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue33346) and has been resolved in python 3.11. Your initial code works fine in python 3.11.

Comment: Thank you! I just installed python 3.11. The former code works fine now!